# How to Record Audio via Terminal Commands and Recognize Voice with Pocketsphinx

Tags: python, bash, record, voice-recognition

I am developing an Offline Artificial-Intelligence Agent.

What I still need to do is overcome the Voice Recognition Problem.

My Problem is that I cannot find a proper way to record the **correct format for Pocketsphinx through the Terminal** in order to embed it to the AI Agent.

Could anyone post any possible method to do this?

*Thanks in Advance.*

Comment: Sorry, you need to provide more details on what you have tried and what exact problems did you have. This terminal command 'rec -r 16000 -e signed-integer -b 16 -c 1 file.wav' should record file.wav in a proper format for example, there are many other ways too.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Sorry if the Information is not enough. Could you tell me what else should I include?

I will try the command and post if it worked for me.

Thanks!

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Well, it records the correct format but it doesn't recognize what I say correctly, even if my Microphone is very good...

Comment: You probably want to have a specific language model for your task, you want to review CMUSphinx tutorial for details.